# Unpivot SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

```
SELECT 
  AssyLotNo, 
  AltLotName, 
  WfrNoDisplay, 
  Param.Display, 
  Param.Value
FROM
  eMap_Data
UNPIVOT 
(Value for Display in 
  (AltLotNumber, WfrNumber, NeedSpeedInfo, MapType, BuildList, Type, ProductGrade,  AssyLotNo)
) as Param
```

Objective of the query above is to have the AssyLotNo field to also be included in the display and value columns. All fields exists in the table eMap_Data, however, I keep getting invalid column name for the field AssyLotNo which clearly exists in eMap_Data.

```
eMap_Data table fields
AssyLotNo | AltLotName | AltLotNumber | WfrNoDisplay | WfrNumber | NeedSpeedInfo | MapType | BuildList     | Type | ProductGrade

Desired output is as follow:
AssyLotNo AltLotName WfrNoDisplay Display        Value
------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC1231   ABC123     01           AltLotName     ABC123
ABC1231   ABC123     01           WfrNumber      01
ABC1231   ABC123     01           NeedSpeedInfo  Y
ABC1231   ABC123     01           MapType        12
ABC1231   ABC123     01           BuildList      1,2,3,4,5,6
ABC1231   ABC123     01           Type           S
ABC1231   ABC123     01           ProductGrade   C
ABC1231   ABC123     01           AssyLotNo      ABC1231
```

Comment: Might it have something to do with AssyLotNo being twice in the sql,  once in the Select list, and once in the UNPIVOT/Param list?   Which one it is complaining about?   change the fieldName/and/or/spelling of the 2nd one and see if that spelling comes up in the error message  (btw, tkx for supplying the table fields)

Comment: I need them to appear 2 times, as part of an XML output. Updated table fields for eMap_data, was missing some fields.

Comment: Complaining about the one in here: UNPIVOT 
(Value for Display in 
  (AltLotNumber, WfrNumber, NeedSpeedInfo, MapType, BuildList, Type, ProductGrade,  AssyLotNo)
)

Comment: donPablo, I changed the name for the second AssyLotNo, still the same error message. Invalid column name.

Comment: After the Param.Value  can you add another ", AssyLotNo as zzz" and remove it from the Unpivot list?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Could you please update it with some sample data of `eMap_Data` and the expected output using that data?

Comment: Updated question for clarity. Desire table output.

Comment: TKX for desired output.  It looks like AssyLotNo is NOT in the list of Unpivot-ed fields, and is only part of the 'key' columns on the left.  Is this the way you want it?  Is this live output? Did you get it by just removing AssyLotNo from the list?

Comment: Yes, if I remove the AssyLotNo in the unpivot list, I got everything else except AssyLotNo. I cannot seem to add AssyLotNo into the list, that's what I want to achieve.

Comment: can you add it with an alias?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the desired output. What does the data look like in `eMap_Data` that produces that output?

Comment: donPablo, the AltLotNumber is supposed to be in the table field. I have added it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Mikael Eriksson, the contents of the Value field are the values of eMap_Data with the Display field being the column name of eMap_Data. I just want to unpivot some of the values of eMap_Data content into the display and value columns in my desired output.

Comment: gotta go, its 11:30pm pdt

Comment: Thanks donPablo. I tried alias (AS) but didn't work as well.

Comment: Is the column `WfrNoDisplay` the same as the column `WfrNumber` in the display column or are they different and just happens to have the same value?

Comment: Different column, just have the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e98b2/1)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
create table eMap_Data
(
  WfrNoDisplay   varchar(20),
  AltLotName     varchar(20),  
  WfrNumber      varchar(20),
  NeedSpeedInfo  varchar(20),
  MapType        varchar(20),
  BuildList      varchar(20),
  Type           varchar(20),
  ProductGrade   varchar(20),
  AssyLotNo      varchar(20)
)


insert into eMap_Data values
('01', 'ABC123', '01','Y','12','1,2,3,4,5,6','S','C','ABC1231')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select E.AssyLotNo,
       E.AltLotName,
       E.WfrNoDisplay,
       T.Display,
       T.Value
from eMap_Data as E
  cross apply (values(AltLotNAme,    'AltLotNAme'),
                     (WfrNumber,     'WfrNumber'), 
                     (NeedSpeedInfo, 'NeedSpeedInfo'),
                     (MapType,       'MapType'), 
                     (BuildList,     'BuildList'), 
                     (Type,          'Type'), 
                     (ProductGrade,  'ProductGrade'), 
                     (AssyLotNo,     'AssyLotNo')
              ) as T(Value, Display)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e98b2/1/0)**:

```
| ASSYLOTNO | ALTLOTNAME | WFRNODISPLAY |       DISPLAY |       VALUE |
|-----------|------------|--------------|---------------|-------------|
|   ABC1231 |     ABC123 |           01 |    AltLotNAme |      ABC123 |
|   ABC1231 |     ABC123 |           01 |     WfrNumber |          01 |
|   ABC1231 |     ABC123 |           01 | NeedSpeedInfo |           Y |
|   ABC1231 |     ABC123 |           01 |       MapType |          12 |
|   ABC1231 |     ABC123 |           01 |     BuildList | 1,2,3,4,5,6 |
|   ABC1231 |     ABC123 |           01 |          Type |           S |
|   ABC1231 |     ABC123 |           01 |  ProductGrade |           C |
|   ABC1231 |     ABC123 |           01 |     AssyLotNo |     ABC1231 |
```

Answer (score 1):

I am always confused by the UNPIVOT syntax so I prefer CROSS APPLY/VALUES instead

```
SELECT AssyLotNo
      ,AltLotName
      ,WfrNoDisplay
      ,CA1.Display
      ,CA1.[Value]
FROM eMap_Data
     CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT *
          FROM (VALUES ('ALotNumber', ALotNumber)
                      ,('WfrNumber', WfrNumber)
                      ,('NeedSpeedInfo', NeedSpeedInfo)
                      ,...
                      ,('AssyLotNo', AssyLotNo)
               ) AS X(Display, [Value])
     ) AS CA1
```

Answer (score 0):

The result set that you get when you run the below query,It does not contain AssyLotNo column:

```
Select * FROM
eMap_Data
UNPIVOT 
(Value for Display in 
(AltLotNumber, WfrNumber, NeedSpeedInfo, MapType, BuildList, [Type], ProductGrade,    AssyLotNo)
) as Param
```

Therefore  when you try selecting a column that does not exist in the result set, you get an error which tells you that it does not exist!!

Comment: Hi, the table eMap_Data contains AssyLotNo. It's the first field. I tried the * approach you showed above, and I got AssyLotNo as the first field as well.

Comment: I guess you are doing just...Select * from eMap_Data...Yes..This ofcourse contains the AssyLotNo column...But when you are doing the unpivot...the result set does not contain this field.